# How to avoid checking for null in jsp

Tags: java, xml, jsp

I want to use JSP page to return dynamic xml.The problem I'm facing is that I've model where some values are null and when they are null I don't wont to display them. So I can do following:

```
if(ampApInfo.getColourcd().equals(null)){   %>

    <ColourCd><%=  ampApInfo.getColourcd() %></ColourCd>

  <%} else if(ampApInfo.getSzWeightColourcd().equals(null)){ %> 


    <SzWeightColourcd><%= ampApInfo.getSzWeightColourcd()  %></SzWeightColourcd>

  <%}%> //and so forth
```

But this makes my code ugly and not practical. Is there a way to avoid that?? 
Can you please provide me with an example how to do it or point to one.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: yeah, don't use null but empty strings if that's what you want to display. Also makes your view thinner.

Comment: as per your code.. it will display when it is null.

Comment: The cod is only an example the main problem is how to avoid multiple if, else if when I don't wan to display tag when the value is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ugliness is caused by using old fashioned *scriptlets* instead of [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info)/[EL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info). With JSTL, it would look more self-documenting (as it uses XML-like markup). With EL you can use the `${}` notation to access bean properties.

Something like this:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty ampApInfo.colourcd}">
        <ColourCd>${ampApInfo.colourcd}</ColourCd>
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${not empty ampApInfo.szWeightColourcd}">
        <ColourCd>${ampApInfo.szWeightColourcd}</ColourCd>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise />
</c:choose>
```

*(note that I inversed the condition, you were printing the elements when the value **is** `null`, which contradicts your own functional requirement)*

#### See also:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Answer (score 0):

`if(object1!=null){`

`do something`

`}else{`

`do something else`

`}`

possible duplicate [Avoiding != null statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271526/how-to-avoid-null-statements-in-java)

Comment: It is similar by not exactly what I wanted. I've looked in to it before I've posted this question and no help :/

Answer (score 0):

Try ternary operator. Also, I think, you have missed not of in your code, so if your code is,

```
     if(ampApInfo.getColourcd() != null){   %>

    <ColourCd><%=  ampApInfo.getColourcd() %></ColourCd>

  <%} else if(ampApInfo.getSzWeightColourcd() != null){ %> 

    <SzWeightColourcd><%= ampApInfo.getSzWeightColourcd()  %></SzWeightColourcd>

  <%}%> //and so forth
```

then, you shall transform to like this.

```
<%
    String str1 = "tag1 data";
    String str2 = "tag2 data";
    String finalStr = str1 != null ? "<tag1>" + str1 + "</tag1>" : (str2 != null ? "<tag2>" + str2 + "</tag2>" : "");
%>
  <%= finalStr%>
```

Comment: Thanks by the thing is I don't want to display tags when the value is null. But this is very helpful thanks. If I can't find other way I'll have to us this.

Comment: I have modified, please check.